# TextBox that remembers it's value

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I am making an app on Windows 8 which has a textbox. I want the textbox to remember it's value when I close the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions on this,

- One is by saving the value in the database or
- by saving it on `Settings`.

Comment: It's a textbox, slightly overkill for this small case imo.
I'd say a small text file will do it quite well and easier.

Comment: that's why I added second option.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- [`Properties.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (and on form closing use `Save`)
- [Windows registry](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)
- Use storage file

But you'll have to do a little work by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For possible solutions, see other answers. Here I give you pseudo-code for storage file.

Create a callback that is called whenever application launches and one for then it closes.

When it launches, load your file, get all of it's text including \n in one string, and set that as text.

When it closes, get the text in the box including \n and write it to the file.

It is quite simple. I would prefer the storage file method here because:

- Properties.Settings is slightly overkill, though it's a viable alternative.
- Windows Registry will work but it won't be cross platform (you may not care about that but it's always a good idea to make sure your app **can** be ported, in case it's successful)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach to save a value to a File.

Here is a very ugly exa,ple to get you started:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Double val;
                val = LoadDoubleValue();
                Console.WriteLine("Previous Value was: " + val);
                Console.Write("Please enter Value for next startup: ");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Double.TryParse(input, out val))
                {
                    SaveDoubleValue(val);
                }

            }

            static Double LoadDoubleValue()
            {
                Double ret = 0;
                if(File.Exists("save.dat")){
                    if (!Double.TryParse(File.ReadAllLines("save.dat")[0], out ret))
                    {
                        ret = 15;
                    }
                }else{
                    ret = 15;
                }
                return ret;
            }

            static void SaveDoubleValue(Double val)
            {
                File.WriteAllLines("save.dat", new string[] { val.ToString() });
            }

        }
    }
```